# $\{f_n\}$ contains a subsequence which converges in $C[0, 1]$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions which are continuous over $[0, 1]$ and continuously differentiable in $(0, 1)$. Assume that $|f_n(x)| \leq 1$ and that $|f_n’(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x \in(0, 1)$ and for each positive integer $n$. Pick out the true statements.
1) $\{f_n\}$ contains a subsequence which converges in $C[0, 1]$.

How to prove this? I know I have to think about Arzela Ascoli Theorem to show the compactness of the sequence. But for this I have to show the sequence ${f_n}$ is closed i.e every sequential limit belongs to ${f_n}$ ... I don't know how to show this .. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: No, you don't have to do this. One can formulate this theorem without the closedness assumption (of course, one has to adjust the claim). Check Wikipedia.

Comment: "But for this I have to show the sequence ${f_n}$ is closed i.e every sequential limit belongs to ${f_n}$" That's a strange thing to say.

Comment: You need that the closure of the set of all $f_n$ is compact, so it's relatively compact. Arzela-Ascoli tells us about such sets too.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzelà–Ascoli_theorem, see the part about differentiable functions.